# Can not handle python Flask redirected() 'POST' method

Tags: python, html, redirect, post, flask

Basically, I have written two views for my Flask webpage:

```
@app.route("/")
def main():
```

and

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def main_post():
```

Later on, I have created two more views in an analogical way:

```
@app.route("/questions")
def questions():
```

and

```
@app.route('/questions', methods=['POST'])
def questions_post():
```

Somehow, my last `['POST']` method does not work at all. Can anyone tell me why? (After sending second `['POST']` there is 'bad request'.)

Here is my code:

```
@app.route("/")
def main():
    questionPath, answersPath, returnPath, databasePath, testName, amount = setup.setup()
    names = database.getListOfTests(databasePath)
    return render_template('index.html', entries = names)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def main_post():
    text = request.form['text']
    processed_text = text
    questionPath, answersPath, returnPath, databasePath, testName, amount = setup.setup()
    names = database.getListOfTests(databasePath)
    if not text in names:
        return render_template('index.html', entries = names)
    else:
        questions2, answers2 = database.getFromDatabase(processed_text,databasePath)
        session['messages'] = questions2
        return redirect(url_for('questions'))

@app.route("/questions")
def questions():
    messages = session['messages']
    session['messages'] = messages
    return render_template('index2.html', entries = messages)

@app.route('/questions', methods=['POST'])
def questions_post():
    text2 = request.form['text2']
    processed_text = text2
    print(processed_text)
    return "XD"
```

And html:

index.html

```
<form action="." method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="text">
    <input type="submit" name="my-form" value="Send">
</form>
```

index2.html

```
<form action="." method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="text2">
    <input type="submit" name="my-form" value="Send2">
</form>
```

Comment: next time use button `{}` to format code.

Comment: always show full error message in question. Text `bad request` is useless. Run it in debug mode - `app.run(debug=True)` - to get more inforamtion in browser.

Comment: Are you sure that it's submitting to the correct URL? It's usually a good idea to let `url_for` build your URLs rather than hardcoding them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"."` is not correct url.

Use empty string `action=""` or remove `action` to send form to the same `url`

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="./questions" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="text2">
<input type="submit" name="my-form" value="Send2">
```

By editing your index2.html `action="./view"` this would work fine.